# What does Application.application mean?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm following a block of sample code that contains the line:

```
 Application.application.addChild(myPrintData);
```

I am placing the code into a custom class (it's a Canvas) and I get an error message when I attempt to use Application.application....
The error is: -Access of undefined property Application
What does it mean and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing the import statement in your custom class.

import mx.core.Application;

Application is a layer of abstraction with a static object application which is the current application instance.
See note below from Reboog711. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Thank you! So does Application.application send a message to the main class file?

Comment: -1. You're almost right.  Application is not a Singleton class; in fact AS3 doesn't have native singletons.  There is no code that prevents you from creating multiple instance of an Application.  However Application does contain some static properties.  The application property is just a layer of abstraction over FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.  FlexGlobals is a class with static properties/methods.  Using FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication is the preferred approach as Application.application is deprecated as of Flex 4.  Tweak your answer for accuracy and I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @user1209902 Application.application is a reference to the main class file.  The code in the original question executes a method (addChild) on the main Application class file.  I'm not sure if "Send a message" is the terminology I'd use.